# How to solve org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Exception

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate, hql

I want to retrieve a single value from database with hibernate query,

Here is my java snippet

```
    String hql="select groupid from group_details where groupname= :groupname and clientid= :clientid";
    Query query=session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter(groupname, groupname);
    query.setParameter(clientid, clientid);
    int result = (int) query.uniqueResult();
    System.out.println(result);
```

I have a bean class `GroupDetails` which has `setter` and `getter` methods for fields.

my mapping file is,

groupDetails.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.aurodisplay.its.beans.GroupDetails"    table="group_details">
    <id column="groupid" name="groupid" type="java.lang.Integer"></id>
    <property column="clientid" name="clientid" type="java.lang.Integer"></property>
    <property column="groupname" name="groupname" type="java.lang.String"></property>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

in Hibernate conf file , I mapped above file,

hibernate.cfg.xml

`<mapping resource="com/aurodisplay/its/xmlFiles/groupDetails.hbm.xml"/>`

I am getting following error ,

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: group_details is not mapped [select groupid from group_details where groupname= :groupname and clientid= :clientid]
org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:158)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:87)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:70)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:257)
org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3056)
org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2945)
org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:688)
org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:544)
org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:281)
org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:229)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:228)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:160)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
```

Can anyone help me in this please.

Comment: The message is clear: "group_details is not mapped". Do you have an entity names "group_details"? No. It's named "GroupDetails".

Comment: yes `GroupDetails` is bean class corresponds to group_details db table

Comment: Learn HQL. HQL doesn't use table names and column names. NEVER. Always entity names and persistent field/property names.

Comment: You do not use table names in hql. `HQL` works with class names.

Comment: `HQL` uses classname and not table name.so instead of using `group_details` use `GroupDetails` in query.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, it solved my problem but now it shows org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [1]. What it might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is a HQL query instead of SQL query, to work with you have to use your class name, so use `GroupDetails` instead of your BDD table name `group_details` as follows:

`String hql="select groupid from GroupDetails where groupname= :groupname and clientid= :clientid";`

EDIT:

I think there is also a problem with your `setParameter`, the first parameter is your field class name not the value itself, so use:

```
query.setParameter("groupname", groupname);
query.setParameter("clientid", clientid);
```

Instead of:

```
query.setParameter(groupname, groupname);
query.setParameter(clientid, clientid);
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank u it solved my problem but now it shows `org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [1]`

Comment: I think the problem is you are using the field values instead of  field name on the query as parameter. Use double quotes `"`.I edit my answer, take a look on it. Hope this helps.